# Find element by id or class in string

Tags: c#, regex

How I can find html element by id or class in string?(regex,C#)

```
<div class="item1">content</div>
<div class="item2">content</div>
```

get only

```
<div class="item1">
```

Comment: Use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), and  [don't use regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: any reason you don't want to user XmlDocument or XDocument instead of regex?

Comment: Unless you are certain that the incoming HTML has a consistent format that will not change, [regex is a poor solution for parting HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583). As @Habib commented, use the HAP for this.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - `XmlDocument` and `XDocument` will throw exceptions with well formed HTML (`<br>` is valid HTML, but not valid XML). A good option is the HAP which also deals with malformed documents and document fragments.

Comment: yes, but no idea from is the xml well formatted or not. In general I agree, Html Agile Pack is better for html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take only div - try this

```
<div (class|id)="myClassNameOrId".*?>
```

instead of `myClassNameOrId` input your own class or id name.
If you want take other elements - replace `div` to other tag's name.